# Socket通信のタイムアウト値と遅延の関係について知りたい

Tags: python, network, socket

私は以下のようなUDP送受信のコードを書きました。
1秒ごとに送信するコード(udpSend.py)と、1秒ごとに待ち受けるコード(udpRecv.py)です。
最初、udpRecv.pyのtimeout値を0.1に設定し、次にtimeout値を5に変更して試してみました。

**udpSend.py**

```
import time
import threading
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1" # 自分に送信

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
startTime = time.time()

def worker():
    try:
        msg = str(time.time()-startTime)
        print(msg)
        s.sendto(msg.encode(), (ADDRESS, PORT))
        time.sleep(8)
    except:
        pass

def scheduler(interval, f, wait = True):
    base_time = time.time()
    next_time = 0
    while True:
        t = threading.Thread(target = f)
        t.start()
        if wait:
            t.join()
        next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
        time.sleep(next_time)

scheduler(1, worker, False)
```

**udpRecv.py**

```
import time
import threading
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''   
PORT = 5000

# ソケットを用意
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
# バインドしておく
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.settimeout(0.1)

def worker():
    try:
        msg, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
        print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(8)
    except:
        pass

def scheduler(interval, f, wait = True):
    base_time = time.time()
    next_time = 0
    while True:
        t = threading.Thread(target = f)
        t.start()
        if wait:
            t.join()
        next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
        time.sleep(next_time)

scheduler(1, worker, False)
```

そうすると、以下のような出力結果が得られました。

**・timeout値=0.1の時**(左側の出力が送信元、右側の出力が受信側)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**・timeout値=5の時**(左側の出力が送信元、右側の出力が受信側)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記の画像から、
timeout値が0.1の時は1秒近い遅延があるのに対し、timeout値が5の時は遅延がほぼない状態に見えます。
これはどういった仕組みで遅延が発生しているのでしょうか？

この場合ではtimeout値を大きくした方が望み通りの結果になっています。
しかし、必ずしもtimeout値を大きくすれば良いというわけでもないのではないかと思うのですが、
どういった時にtimeout値を大きくしたり小さくしたりすれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## timeout = 0.1

```
msg, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
```

受信スレッドが起動されて0.1秒以内にデータが来なければ、データが読まれるのは次に受信スレッドが起動されたタイミングですので、0.1～0.9秒のタイムラグが生じます。送受信とも1秒ごとに動作するので以後このタイムラグは維持されます。

## timeout = 5

```
msg, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
```

5秒待つ受信スレッドが毎秒起動されるので、データが届いたタイミングで必ず1つはスレッドが生きています。ですので、到達したデータはほぼリアルタイムで読み込まれます。

> しかし、必ずしもtimeout値を大きくすれば良いというわけでもないのではないかと思うのですが、

これはその通りです。が、一般論として「大きくすればよい」「小さくすればよい」という話ではありません。何がやりたいか次第です。

受信スレッドが1秒ごとに起動されるのが前提なら、タイムアウトは1秒以上あっても意味がありません。が、目的に対して受信スレッドを1秒ごとに起動する、という方法自体が妥当でないのであれば、それについてタイムアウトをどうするかの議論も無意味になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。このような場合、timeout値を0.1にしたままでタイムラグを維持せずに次のループに回すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？そのようなことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 回答に書いたとおりです。目的がわからないのでなんとも言いようがありません。

Comment: 説明が不足していて申し訳ありません。いま、Blenderという3DCGソフトでのスクリプトをPythonで書いていて、udpRecv.pyと似たような記述のコードを書いています。Blender上では、timeout値を大きくするとその間にBlenderの計算リソースが占有されてしまうからなのか、画面がフリーズしてしまうのです。そのため、timeout値を小さくしたまま一定時間間隔でループを回すようなコードを書かなければいけないのですが、そうするとタイムラグが発生してしまい、どっちにしても悪い面があって困っているという状態です。特定のソフトウェアのみで起こる現象のため回答して頂くのは難しいかもしれませんが、説明だけさせてください。また、Blenderではソフトの計算リソースの占有を防ぐためか、whileループも使えず、上記のように一定時間ごとにループを実行するためのmodalOperatorという機能があって、そういった縛りの中でコーディングになっています。

Comment: 前提が全く違う話になるので、新たな質問として投稿してください

Comment: 別の質問として投稿をしてみました。https://is.gd/KPheXl